# Conformal map from the region outside a semicircle to the region outside a disk of radius $\frac{R}{\sqrt 2}$ centred at the origin

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, conformal-geometry

Can I really get a conformal map from the region outside a semicircle, $\mathbb{C} \setminus S_R = \left\{(x_1, x_2):|x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2 = R^2, x_2 \leq 0 \right\}$ to the region outside a disk $D$ of radius $\frac{R}{\sqrt 2}$ centred at the origin, $\mathbb{C} \setminus D$? I should end up with $h(u) = \frac{iR + u + i \sqrt{R^2 − u^2}}{2}$, with $u =  x_1 +ix_2$, but I cannot understand where this solution could come from.
I had the following ideas.

1. Mapping the region outside the semicircle to the upper half plane. The region outside the semicircle, ($\mathbb{C} \setminus S_R$), can be mapped to the upper half plane using the function ($f(z) = \sqrt{R^2 - z^2}$). This function takes the points outside the semicircle and maps them to the upper half plane.
2. Mapping the upper half plane to the unit disk. The upper half plane could be mapped to the unit disk using the Möbius transformation ($g(w) = \frac{w - i}{w + i}$). This function takes the points in the upper half plane and maps them to the inside of the unit disk.
3. Scaling the unit disk to a disk of radius ($\frac{R}{\sqrt 2}$). The unit disk can be scaled to a disk of radius ($\frac{R}{\sqrt 2}$) using the function ($s(z) = \frac{R}{\sqrt{2}} z$). This function scales the points inside the unit disk to the inside of a disk of radius ($\frac{R}{\sqrt 2}$).

This does not give me the desired result, but I cannot see any other possible solution. What steps should I take? Any hints for arriving at the correct solution are appreciated.

Comment: Has anyone managed to assimilate and process my misconceptions? Any clarifying answers are most welcome.

Comment: the upper half plane is simply connected and the outside of the semicircle isn't, so something is wrong

Comment: @Conrad OK, what do you recommend? Do you have any more detailed hints?

Comment: the function you mention doesn't sound right as for $-R \le u \le R$ you do not get a value on the image boundary circle; the idea is to use a Mobius transform to send the semicircle to two perpendicular lines through the origin (so something like $a\frac{z+R}{z-R}$) keeping track where infinity goes, then compress the three quarters you get the outside sent too to a half plane (again keeping track of infinity), then send that to the unit circle with infinity to $0$ and then invert with $z \to c/z$ to get the outside circle of right radius and send infinity back to itself

Comment: @Conrad Thank you very much. I did not understand when you say "keeping track where infinity goes, then compress the three quarters you get the outside sent too to a half plane (again keeping track of infinity)". Could you explain more?

Comment: when you use a Mobius transform $e^{it}\frac{z+R}{z-R}$ to send the semicircle to two perpendicular half lines through $0$, the inside gets sent to a quadrant, so the outside gets sent to the other $3$ quadrants, while $\infty$ goes to $e^{it}$ - for example $t=0$ gives you $3$rd quadrant for the inside and $\infty$ going to $1$; then $z \to z^{2/3}$ sends those three quadrants conformally to the half-plane  at angle $60$ wr positive $x$ axis, keeping infinity at $1$, then you need a rotation to straighten the half plane to say $\Re z>0$ which sends infinity to $e^{\pi/6}$etc

Comment: The goal is to get conformally to the inside of the unit disc in such a way that the image of infinity in the half plane is sent to the origin, so you can invert (or you can directly send a half-plane to the circle outside and the image of infinity to infinity and then dilate to get the required radius)

Comment: @Conrad  I used the transformation $e^{-i \frac{\pi}{6}}z$ in order to rotate the half-plane so that it lies along the positive real axis. After that, I used an exponential transformation to map the half-plane to the unit circle by the transformation $e^z$,
which sends infinity to 0. Finally, I used inversion and scaling to map the unit circle to a circle of radius $\frac{R}{\sqrt 2}$ by the transformation $\frac{R}{\sqrt 2} \frac{1}{z}$. The final result doesn't add up for me, I've definitely done something wrong... What's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: $e^z$ is not injective - you need a Mobius transform to map half plane to unit disc, but you have to make sure infinity gets sent to origin (or infinity) and that can be tricky - another idea is to map $\infty$ somewhere inside the unit disc and then use a disc automorphism to send it to the origin; or choose $t$ carefully so after straightening, $\infty$ goes to $1$ or $i$ and then you can use the standard Mobius transform;

Comment: @Conrad We are seeking ${\lim_{z \to \infty}} e^{-i\frac{\pi}{6} z}$, right?
If we consider $z = x_1 + ix_2$, then by De Moivre's Theorem, we have
$e^{-i \frac{\pi}{6} z} = e^{-i \frac{\pi}{6} (x_1+ix_2)} = \frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{6} x_1) + i \sin(\pi x_1)}{e^{x_2}}$. Everything has to depend on along which path $z \to \infty$: if $x$ is fixed and $y \to \infty$, the limit converges to $0$. Right? Or did I not understand (as is likely) what you wanted to say?

Comment: @Conrad I have not yet managed to solve the problem, I cannot even "use a disc automorphism to send it to the origin". Some more advice and clarification is most welcome.

Comment: Not to add to comments as at some point they get moved to chat, I will put an answer sketch but do not really want to get into the nitty-gritty details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem asks to show explicitly a conformal isomorphism between a semicircle exterior and a disc exterior. The main issue here is that while both are "one hole domains" bounded by circle arcs in the extended Mobius sense (so they are conformally isomorphic by Riemann mapping theorem extended version to finite hole domains since both are isomorphic to punctured discs), the angles do not match, so we need to do a boundary straightening which kills conformality there (conformal isomorphisms preserve angles inside the domain where they are so), hence such an isomorphism will not extend conformally over the boundary and we have to be careful.

For the easier problem of doing the semicircle inside to disc, the angles are $90$ vs $180$ so a squaring function will do, but here the angles are $270$ vs $180$ due to orientation so we need a power $2/3$ at some point to match the boundary angles.

First, we use a Mobius isomorphism (which is conformal in the extended plane) to send the semicircle (which has angle $90$ between the arc and the segment on the boundary) to two perpendicular rays and since we need to deal with the exterior, we need to keep track where $\infty$ goes.

As such a map we can use $e^{it}\frac{z+R}{z-R}$ which sends the intersection of the boundary components to $0, \infty$, hence sending the two to perpendicular rays through the origin and $\infty$ to $e^{it}$. For example, if $t=0$, checking where $0, -iR$ are sent we see that the segment is sent to the negative ray and the lower half circle to the upper imaginary ray, while infinity gets sent to $1$ so the inside of the semicircle goes to the third quadrant, and the outside to the rest, so the three quadrants remaining including the positive ray and the lower imaginary ray.

Now since we need to get to a disc, we need to straighten the angle and for this we use the conformal map $z \to z^{2/3}$ which is well defined on our three quadrant region; we can think of it as $re^{i\theta} \to r^{2/3}e^{2i \theta/3}$ where here $-\pi < \theta < \pi/2$; again for $t=0$ this sends the two boundary rays to the rays through angles $\pi/3, -2\pi/3$ (up and down respectively, so they continue each other forming a line), hence sends our three quadrant region to the right-hand plane bounded by this and keeps infinity at $1$ of course.

Now we can use a Mobius transform to send that to the unit disc and $1$ to $0$ and invert $z \to c/z$, or directly send the half plane to the unit disc exterior and $1 \to \infty$ and then dilate to get the radius we want, but an explicit form of this can be complicated so we can proceed in stages.

First we rotate the half plane to become the right half or the upper one, then use the standard Mobius transforms (eg $\frac{z-1}{z+1}$ for the right half plane $\Re z >0$) to send those to the unit disc and then use a disc automorphism $\frac{z-a}{1-\bar a z}$ to send $a$ the image of $1$ to $0$ and finally invert $z \to c/z$. To avoid this, one can try to see if there is a $t$ st when we do the straightening and rotating, the final image of $\infty$ is either $1$ or $i$ in the right half plane or upper half plane so then we can dispense with the disc automorphisms and use the standard Mobius maps.

So as a summation - the required map will be a composition of Mobius transform with $z^{2/3}$ with another Mobius transform and the reasons mentioned above, make this unavoidable for matching the boundary angles of the original domain to the ones of the target domain